# How to merge these two function with Laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I need to export final amount after calculation of all payable and receivable of a member now I do in two function how to merge them

```
public function memberReceivable($id){

    return $this->join('transactions', 'transactions.id', '=', 'member_transactions.transaction_id')
    ->leftjoin('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'transactions.account_id')
    ->selectRaw("transactions.unit as currency,sum(transactions.amount) as amount")
    ->where('accounts.type','accountsReceivable')
    ->where('member_transactions.member_id',$id)
    ->groupBy('transactions.unit')->get();    
}

public function memberPayable($id){

    return $this->join('transactions', 'transactions.id', '=', 'member_transactions.transaction_id')
             ->leftjoin('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'transactions.account_id')
             ->selectRaw("transactions.unit as currency,sum(transactions.amount) as amount")
             ->where('accounts.type','accountsPayable')
             ->where('member_transactions.member_id',$id)
             ->groupBy('transactions.unit')->get();
}
```

Comment: probably create a merge function and return both functions in that one function

Answer (score 1):

```
public function member($id = null, $type = ""){
    $response = $this->join('transactions', 'transactions.id', '=', 
    'member_transactions.transaction_id')
    ->leftjoin('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'transactions.account_id')
    ->selectRaw("transactions.unit as currency,sum(transactions.amount) as amount");

    if($type){
      $response->where('accounts.type', $type);
    }

    if($id){
      $response->where('member_transactions.member_id',$id);
    }

    $response->groupBy('transactions.unit')->get();

    return $response;
}
```

You can try it.

Comment: ok thanks, if I want to use this function for all member how can I use this

Comment: thanks for your time, suppose if I do not pass any $id and $type function should give me all report